# How to add Sign Up Fee on Invoice Email

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm working on customizing Woocommerce's Emails on my installation and I'm trying to add a label with the sign up fee per product on the Customer Invoice email inside subscription-info.php

I purely want to print the value to a cell but I haven't been successful. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Edit: I'm using WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin.

Comment: so you are using subscription plugin for your store right? there is plenty of plugins out there so please mentioned which plugin you are using in order to get some help

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Going to edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do this by adding

```
$sign_up_fee   = $product->get_sign_up_fee();
```

On email-order-items.php inside $product if

```
if ( is_object( $product ) ) {
    $sku           = $product->get_sku();
    $purchase_note = $product->get_purchase_note();
    $image         = $product->get_image( $image_size );
    $sign_up_fee   = $product->get_sign_up_fee();
}
```

Then I echo it on a new